# Github Packages not proxying requests

Tags: npm, github-package-registry

I'm using Github Packages as my npm registry and have some private packages hosted there. I want all npm install requests to proxy through Github Packages. According to [this blog post](https://github.blog/2019-09-11-proxying-packages-with-github-package-registry-and-other-updates/) and [these docs](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/using-github-packages-with-your-projects-ecosystem/configuring-npm-for-use-with-github-packages#installing-a-package) this should happen by default. However, when I run `npm install` on my project, I get a `package-lock.json` file that uses Github Packages registry for my custom private package, but the default npm registry for others.

Example snippet from `package-lock.json`:

```
{
  "name": "linting",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 1,
  "requires": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/code-frame": {
      "version": "7.10.4",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/code-frame/-/code-frame-7.10.4.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-8765asdf7865sadf+asdfsdfsdf/sfadsfg876675safsfsdfsdf678==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "@babel/highlight": "^7.10.4"
      }
    },
    "@my-org/prettier-config": {
      "version": "2.0.1",
      "resolved": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/download/@my-org/prettier-config/2.0.1/sdg8765dsfg8675sdfg8765dsfg7685",
      "integrity": "sha512-dsfgdfgdfgsdg56456ftg656h6h+sdfg876sdfg7865sdfg765675sdfg7865==",
      "dev": true
    }
  }
}
```

I'm wondering whether my `.npmrc` file is setup incorrectly. In the project root it looks like this:

```
registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/my-org
```

And the `.npmrc` in my home folder looks like this:

```
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=dsfg8765sdfg765dsfg685
```

Are my configs wrong, or is something else happening here that appears to be stopping the proxy?

Note all org names and keys changed to nonsense for the sake of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a "/" to the end to make it like this
registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/my-org/

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please don't post suggestions as answer. Visit this question about [posting a suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281010/posting-a-suggestion-when-im-not-sure-about-the-answer).

Comment: This is the answer